# Cassandra Rebuild starts from beginning everytime it is restarted

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Need help. Recently we have added new DC in existing cluster. We are streaming historical data from old DC to new one using rebuild command on each node in new DC.

Problem that I am facing is, because of high data volume and longer GC pauses, Cassandra services in old DC nodes stops and when it happens, rebuild also stops. And when we start it again, it shows it is streaming same amount of data again.

We are using Cassandra 3.11.x. As per Cassandra documentation, if rebuild command stops and you run it again, it resumes the streaming from the offset where it stopped. But doesn't seem to be happening.

Can anyone please help to understand how this rebuild works after restart and how can I overcome this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to run rebuild on all the nodes simultaneously? Or one-at-a-time?

Comment: One at a time. One observation I had, is if new node completes entire streaming from any of the old DC node then that token range is saved in `available_ranges` table and then if I run the rebuild again then it does not stream data from that node.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what you mean by "doesn't seem to be happening". Ideally you need to explicitly describe how you determined that it isn't "happening". Otherwise, it's a bit difficult to give you a meaningful answer.

In any case, nodes have a record of which token ranges and which keyspaces have been streamed and are available to be served. This information is stored in the `system.available_ranges` table.

Once a certain range of tokens for a given keyspace has been successfully streamed to a node, an entry is created in the `available_ranges` table so if you try to re-run a `rebuild` or `bootstrap resume`, the completed ranges won't get re-streamed again. Cheers!

Comment: Hi Erick, Thanks for reply. I though `doesn't seem to be happening` will be inferred as starting from beginning as I have mentioned the same in the question.
The situation is, if for first run of rebuild, `netstats` is showing `X` TB to be transferred then, if you start the rebuild again, it will again show you still `X` TB to be transferred. This size is not reducing. I hope this clarifies

I will check for `available_ranges` table.

Comment: I checked in old as well new DC, available_ranges table is empty.

Comment: One observation, if rebuild it stopped in between and streaming from any node is complete then only that node's data is not streamed again by triggering rebuild again but for all other nodes it starts streaming data from beginning. Is there any setting to store the already streamed data while rebuilding?